# How do I use formset data as initial data in my forms? Error is ' The inline value did not match the parent instance.'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a formset that I use to collect some data.  I also want to use that same data as the initial data to a different formset.  In order to do this, I have a form that looks like...

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs,):
        dropdown = kwargs.pop('dropdown', None)
        super(TeamFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(team_pk=dropdown)
```

After a bunch of searching and massaging....I've gotten this to work exactly how I want.  The challenge I'm having now is when I'm loading this form, I am getting an error that says The inline value did not match the parent instance.  I've done some research on the querysets and formsets and I understand django knows how this data was created originally, but I am trying to essentially use the values as a starting point for this form.

I have seen that get_initial might be available for formsets.  Is there some other way I should be getting the data rather than the way I am going about it above?  The data is dynamic, and since I've already captured it in another part of the system, I can't see why I shouldn't be able to use the values at a minimum as a starting point for a different form.

Comment: This happens automatically if your form and model structure are sane and you use [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). See the example with author and book. Replace author with Team and Book with Player and you have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to figure out my approach.  I simply needed to override GET.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
 
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        dropdown = self.kwargs["pk"]
        contacts = MyModel.objects.filter(company_pk=dropdown)
```